# How To Remove Ubuntu Without The Ubuntu Partition

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I would like to remove my Ubuntu which is dual-booting with windows 7.

I don't remember how I installed it, but the Ubuntu partition does not appear on the Disk Management. (Have a SYSTEM partition of 2GB, what is that?)

I installed the EasyBCD to remove Ubuntu from the boot menu, but after a restart the boot menu is still there with the Ubuntu option, and reappears in the EasyBCD after I deleted it.
I have no idea what to do now, can any one suggest anything. I really prefer not to format the drive.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a live-CD or live-USB of Ubuntu, you can boot into that and use GParted to remove the linux partition and extend into the unallocated space, as Nayanna has suggested or follow the same procedure and reformat the linux partition to NTFS or FAT .. something that Windows will recognize, effectively giving you two partitions, one for Win system files and one for storage (my personal choice is 2 partitions).

If you do have the live-medium available but GParted is not included, you can use the Ubuntu Software Center or the terminal command `sudo apt-get install gparted` to get it.
Here is a link to an informative tutorial on GParted, if you are not familiar: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

Answer (score -1):

1)If you have installed ubuntu inside windows(using wubi)

Goto Control panel-> Uninstall a program and Uninstall ubuntu entry

2)If you insall ubuntu in dual- boot

Delete the Linux partition from disk management
Then Extend the partition to current windows partition
Boot windows from recovery disk
Choose "Repair Your Computer," go to "Troubleshoot," and then enter a Command Prompt. Type the following command

```
 bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Then reboot your computer
For more details refer this link
http://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-or-linux-after-dual-booting-508710422

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OK I will change it

Comment: The thing is that there is no visible Ubuntu partition on the Disk Management.

Comment: Do you install ubuntu inside windows( have you install ubuntu using wubi)